# how to sort table by parameter on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report on SSRS.
I have order and Planned Start column on table.
I want to add now the option to order by line or by Planned start time.

I mean if I choose line, our report must be sort for line
if I choose planned start time, report must be sort for planned start time

How should I do like this?
Could you help me please?

[image]

Comment: [Interactive Sort Buttons](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627509(v=sql.100).aspx) seems to be what you want, also hilighted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17374502/6167855)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a report parameter called something like "Order By", and make the available values as Line and Planned Start Date. Then, lets say you have a simple report with just one Details group, go into the Group Properties and in the Sort tab, set the sort expression as something like:

```
=iif(Parameters!OrderBy.Value = "Line",Fields!LineNumber.Value,Fields!PlannedStartDate.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable to the SQL script @param then pass it from the parameter just like passing any other parameter. SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY @param

Comment: I solved this problem like this:                  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LYG7W8ZKxY&t=483s                                                               Thanks for your helping:)

Comment: Thats is what I said. I'm sorry I wasnt clear in my explanation.